# Extract multiple occurrences of a substring using Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

Given the following string:

```
'<p><a href="china">China</a><br><a href="india">India</a><br><a
href="korea">Korea</a><br><a href="malaysia">Malaysia</a><br><a
href="thailand">Thailand</a></p>'
```

I'd like to use Powershell to extract all of the countries listed therein. In other words I want to return @(China,India,Korea,Malaysia,Thailand).

Have tried using regex but can't find the right pattern, for example:

```
'<p><a href="china">China</a><br><a href="india">India</a><br><a href="korea">Korea</a><br><a href="malaysia">Malaysia</a><br><a href="thailand">Thailand</a></p>'  -match '(<a href="[A-Z a-z]*">[A-Z a-z]*</a>)+'
$matches
```

Which returns:

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                            
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                            
1                              <a href="china">China</a>                                                                                                                                                                        
0                              <a href="china">China</a>
```

Any suggestions? Is regex the right approach here?

P.S. Note that the snippet is not well-formed so I can't simply convert it to XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$Matches` automatic variable contains information about matched capturing groups of last `-match` operation, not information about matches. If you want to get multiple matches of pattern, then you have to use `Matches` method from `[Regex]` class:

```
$InputString='<p><a href="china">China</a><br><a href="india">India</a><br><a href="korea">Korea</a><br><a href="malaysia">Malaysia</a><br><a href="thailand">Thailand</a></p>'
$Pattern='<a href="[A-Z a-z]*">([A-Z a-z]*)</a>'
$Countries=[Regex]::Matches($InputString,$Pattern)|ForEach-Object {$_.Groups[1].Value}
$Countries
```

Although for parsing HTML you better to use some HTML parser as [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27942669) propose to you.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are never a good way to handle HTML (though often they are tempting). You can parse the HTML and extract the data you want without using any regex:

```
PS C:\> $d = '<p><a href="china">China</a><br><a href="india">India</a><br><a
href="korea">Korea</a><br><a href="malaysia">Malaysia</a><br><a
href="thailand">Thailand</a></p>'


PS C:\> $html = New-Object -ComObject "HTMLFile"

PS C:\> $html.IHTMLDocument2_write($d)

PS C:\> $html.getElementsByTagName('A') | select -expandProperty innerText
China
India
Korea
Malaysia
Thailand
```

Comment: Nice. Didn't know about expandProperty. Thanks Duncan.

Comment: Mostly with Powershell 3 and later you don't need to use `expandProperty` as you can usually just use dot notation. I don't know why it doesn't work here: `($html.getElementsByTagName('A')).innerText` gives nothing while `$html.getElementsByTagName('A') | select -expandProperty innerText` works fine. I guess it must be because `$html` is a COM object.

Answer (score 0):

The following Regex should do the trick:

```
(?<=><a\shref="\w+">)\w+
```

ML

Answer (score 0):

```
$InputString='<p><a href="china">China</a><br><a href="india">India</a><br><a href="korea">Korea</a><br><a href="malaysia">Malaysia</a><br><a href="thailand">Thailand</a></p>'
$Pattern='(?<=>)\w+?(?=<)'

([Regex]::Matches($InputString,$Pattern)).Value
```

China

India

Korea

Malaysia

Thailand